# Scrolling of CollectionView in CustomKeyboard JERKs

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, scrollview, custom-keyboard

Facing an issue with the scrolling of CollectionView. When user drags the scroll and leaves it the collectionView scroll jerks just before stopping. The jerk/flicker is very less but I am not able to understand why it is not as smooth as collection view usually is.

I am just using these methods to load CollectionView:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 500;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EmojiCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:EmojiCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Below is the link of the code:  [CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssxy1vaj2btg8cq/CustomKeyBoard.zip?dl=0)

Comment: no one will probably download your code and review unless you add some basic code and description the question.

Comment: @Shubhank - I think its better now

Comment: any other methods of scrollview or Collectionview your override ?